# Wordpress freezes when accessing the backend

Tags: wordpress

It's been a while now that i'm using Wordpress; and I know it quite well.
But this time, I've got a problem I've never seen :

My website freezes as soon as I try to go to the backend.

The frontend works, but when I go to /wp-admin, it stops working and eventually fires a "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error.
Then the whole website (and FTP) is then down for about 5 minutes, then it comes back.

I don't know what as been changed since last time it worked.

Here's what I did try so far :

- override my Wordpress folder with a fresh install
- disable plugins (renamed wp-content/plugins to wp-content/pluginsOLD)
- disable current theme (renamed wp-content/themes/my-theme to wp-content/themes/my-themeOLD)
- edited wp-config.php file to [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) with WP_DEBUG, WP_DEBUG_LOG and SAVEQUERIES set to true; no debug.log is generated.

I also considered a server issue and waited for about 24hours.  But my other websites (which are hosted on the same place) just work fine.

Any ideas about this ? I'm getting mad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My host had blacklisted my IP, that's why I wasn't able to access it. 
I guess each time I was trying to access the backend, they did freeze my website to avoid an attack or something.
Well, this may be interesting for others.  If I had knew it, I would have change my IP... :/